# Error: Unknown dataProvider function: toJSON

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, dataprovider

```
import  restProvider   from 'ra-data-simple-rest'
const dataProvider= process.env.REACT_APP_API+'/api/link'

<Admin dataProvider={restProvider(dataProvider) }>
    <Resource name='endpoint' options={{label:'MyLabel'}} list={myList} />
  </Admin>
```

Response from API IS

```
 [{id:'',name:''},{id:'',name:''},{id:'',name:''},{id:'',name:''}]
```

```
Error: Unknown dataProvider function: toJSON
    at Proxy.<anonymous> (useDataProvider.ts:96:1)
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at Object.parseData `your text`(<anonymous>:8:116)
    at <anonymous>:10:2186
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:10:2114
    at i (<anonymous>:10:2706)
    at <anonymous>:10:2993
    at _ (<anonymous>:10:3119)
    at <anonymous>:10:3363
```

- 

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to include the option param to configure json data

```
import { fetchUtils } from 'react-admin';



const fetchJson = (url, options = {}) => {
    if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' });
    } 
    return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
}

<Admin dataProvider={restProvider(dataProvider, fetchJson) }>
```

[Doc](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html)

Comment: Tried , But getting same error.
if (!options.headers) is false in my case,